# Pre-commit, Markdownlint: Executable `\usr\bin\ruby2.7` not found

Tags: ruby, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

### Context

While trying to run `pre-commit` I experienced the following error:

```
Markdownlint.............................................................Failed
- hook id: markdownlint
- exit code: 1

Executable `/usr/bin/ruby2.7` not found
```

And the command:`ruby --version` yields:

```
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

### Question

How can I ensure the `pre-commit` finds the right `ruby` version?

Answer (score 0):

Someone experienced a similar issue for `ruby 2.5` over [here](https://github.com/markdownlint/markdownlint/issues/352). The issue in that case seemed to be a broken `symlink`.

The solution was:

```
pre-commit clean
```

followed by running

```
pre-commit run --all-files
```

This seemed to remove all the `pre-commit` environments/repositories and re-installed them from scratch based on the `.pre-commit-config.yaml`, `pyproject.toml` and `setup.py`. Running the `pre-commit run --all-files` takes a while after cleaning the environment, and resolved the issue of Ruby not being found.

Comment: did you recently upgrade your computer?

Comment: I think I indeed upgraded from Ubuntu 21.04 to 22.04 somewhere in the last 3-6 weeks. I am not exactly sure whether this bug has been introduced since I upgraded, it may well be, as I ignored it for a while.

Comment: ah yeah if you're using `language_version: system` and you upgrade the system out from under pre-commit that'll happen.  there's special code for python but not for ruby -- if you want to contribute a fix for it it would just need [this method](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/170335cbb63796761d592f8eacd66c78de8dd912/pre_commit/languages/ruby.py#L24) to be implemented (python has a complete example)

Comment: Thank you for the explicit instructions. Off-topic, for completeness, I am time constrained with different priorities in the upcoming 2-4 weeks, so within that timeframe I will most likely not implement that fix.